# How to use Repo module in my model file

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

In my **Tag** model code

```
schema "tags" do
  field :name, :string
  field :parent, :integer # parent tag id
  timestamps
end

def add_error_when_not_exists_tag_id(changeset, params) do
  tags = Repo.all(Tag)
  is_exists_tag_id = Enum.reduce(tags, fn(x, acc) -> acc || (x.id === params.parent) end)
  if is_exists_tag_id, do: changeset, else: add_error(changeset, :parent, "not exists parent!")
end
```

Above code caused a error below.

```
(UndefinedFunctionError) undefined function: Repo.all/1 (module Repo is not available)
```

Can I fix the error ?

The Tag model is **nested** tag model.

Tag can has parent tag.

---

Finaly code is below. This is work fine.

In model

```
def add_error_when_not_exists_tag_id(changeset, params, tags) do
  is_exists_tag_id = Enum.reduce(tags, false, fn(x, acc) -> acc || (Integer.to_string(x.id) === params["parent"]) end)
  if is_exists_tag_id, do: changeset, else: add_error(changeset, :parent, "The tag is not exists.")
end
```

In controller

```
def create(conn, %{"tag" => tag_params}) do
  changeset = Tag.changeset(%Tag{}, tag_params)
  |> Tag.add_error_when_not_exists_tag_id(tag_params, Repo.all(Tag))
  //
  // ...
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can't use the `Repo` variable as it isn't available in this module. You will need to alias it:

```
alias MyApp.Repo
```

In controllers this is handled for you in `web.ex` which gets called in your module with:

```
use MyApp.Web, :controller
```

However, I **strongly** suggest that you avoid using `Repo` in your model. Your models are meant to be pure, this means that they should not have side effects. Calling a function in your model should always have the same output for a particular input (idempotence).

In this example you could change the implementation of the function to:

```
def add_error_when_not_exists_tag_id(changeset, params, tags) do
  is_exists_tag_id = Enum.reduce(tags, fn(x, acc) -> acc || (x.id === params.parent) end)
  if is_exists_tag_id, do: changeset, else: add_error(changeset, :parent, "not exists parent!")
end
```

You can call `Repo.all` in your controller and pass the tags through to the function.

If you have more complex behaviour, consider creating a `TagService` module which uses the function as well as calling the `Repo.all`

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer! I will try write in `tag_controller.ex` the validation logic. Because, I don't have other logic so far for the Tag model.

Comment: Oops, I made a mistake... I will try write in `tag.ex` the pure logic as function and call the function from controller. I got the point. `changeset = Tag.changeset(%Tag{}, tag_params) |> Tag.add_error_when_not_exists_tag_id(tag_params)`